# Changing simple_form date input to have three string inputs instead of three drop down menus

Tags: datepicker, simple-form

I'm using simple_form gem on a form, and want to use date fields with three text_fields fields instead of three select fields.

I tried this:

```
<%= profile_form.simple_fields_for :birthday do |date| %>
  <%= date.input :day, :as => :string, :label => "Dia", :input_html => { :maxlength => 2 } %>
  <%= date.input :month, :as => :string, :label => "Mês", :input_html => { :maxlength => 2 } %>
  <%= date.input :year, :as => :string, :label => "Ano", :input_html => { :maxlength => 4 } %>
<%- end -%>
```

But that creates three div's, three labels and it's a mess.
The ideal scenario was to have one label and three string fields in line.

Any ideas how I can create that custom input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the mailing list of the simple_form I finally got it.
The custom input looks like this:

```
class CustomDateInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
   def input
    "#{@builder.text_field("day", input_html_options)}".html_safe +
    "#{@builder.text_field("month", input_html_options)}".html_safe +
    "#{@builder.text_field("year", input_html_options)}".html_safe
  end

  #Makes the label target the day input
  def label_target
    "day"
  end
end
```

The day, month and year are virtual attributes that needed to be created. 
I've added them to a module so that they can be mixed in my models.
The module looks like this:

```
module Extensions
  module DateFields

    attr_accessor :day, :month, :year

    def fulldate
      Date.parse("#{@day}-#{@month}-#{@year}")
    end
  end
end
```

Now in my models I can do this:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  before_save :update_birthday

  include Extensions::DateFields

  private
  def update_birthday
    unless fulldate == true || nil?
      self.birthday=fulldate
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you search for Custom Inputs on [SimpleForm's readme](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) I believe you can write a custom input like such..

```
# app/inputs/inline_input.rb
class InlineInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    "<span>#{@builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)}</span>".html_safe
  end
end
```

Then call it like this

```
<%=profile_form.simple_fields_for :birthday do |date| %>
  <%= date.input :day, :as => :inline, :label => false, :input_html => { :maxlength => 2 } %>
  <%= date.input :month, :as => :inline, :label => false, :input_html => { :maxlength => 2 } %>
  <%= date.input :year, :as => :inline, :label => false, :input_html => { :maxlength => 4 } %>
<%- end -%>
```

Comment: Thank you mike. I've tried that, but each input still gets rendered inside a DIV. I'm guessing I should try to group the 3 DIV's using CSS? But still, if the DateTime Input comes with three dropdowns it should be possible to change them to three spans... I just can't figure that out :/